# Do i have to burn all my animate paintings?

Tags: practical-islam, drawing

Assalamualikum,

I recently learn drawing/ painting animate objects with with eyes , mouth and nose is haraam.

I have decided to only paint landscape from now on.

However I'm not sure what I should do with all of my drawing and paintings. Do I have to rid of them and burn them or can I still keep them as I had no idea it was haraam during the time.

Answer (score -1):

As we know from Hadith. Allah will ask to those person who used to painting animated things, Allah will ask them to give life to those paintings.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Those who make these pictures will be
> punished on the Day of Resurrection, and it will be said to them.
> 'Make alive what you have created.'"

Reference    : Sahih al-Bukhari 5951,
In-book reference : Book 77, Hadith 167

It is best if you burn them. Since you didn't know it was haram you will not get any sin.

1. Repent to Allah
2. Burn or destroy those paintings
3. Never do it again

If you don't have any access to some drawing you have drawn in past, and can't able to burn them. Allah will not punish you for that.
Because in surah bakarah Allah says :

"Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity."

https://quran.com/2/286